# Quantisation of radiation energy

Tags: energy, visible-light, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

I am currently studying about the *dual nature of radiation and matter.* I have come across how the radiation energy is quantified by saying that it is built up of ***discrete units.*** Though I fairly have a grasp on this issue, my textbook has a statement that is not clear. It says,

> Observation on photoelectric effect imply that in the event of matter-light interaction, *absorption of energy takes place in discrete units of hv.* This is not quite the same as saying that light consists of particles, each of energy *hv.*

What does it mean? Aren't the two sentences contrasting thems? If not, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's a subtle ontological distinction on the nature of light  being made

Comment: @InertialObserver can you please elaborate?